# Is this recursive function quadratic time complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

The objective of the below code is to take consecutive repeating characters and shift them so they're not repeating anymore. i.e.: 'aaabbcc' -> 'abcacba' if it's not possible, return None.

```
    function sortEvo(str, result) {
        result = result || []

        str = str.split('').sort()

        if (str.length === 0)
            return result.join('')

        const arrLen = str.length - 1
        const resLen = result.length - 1

        if (str[arrLen] !== result[resLen]) 
            result.push(str.pop())
        else if (str[arrLen] !== result[0])
            result.unshift(str.pop())
        else if (str[0] !== result[resLen])
            result.push(str.shift())
        else return 'None'

        return sortEvo(str.join(''), result) 
    }
```

At first sight, it looks linear time, but I'm unsure because of the shift() and unshift() that makes it iterate through the array to re-index the elements.

Comment: `shift`, `unshift`? Yeah, maybe, probably. Doesn't matter. `str.split('').sort()` and `str.join('')` definitely have linear runtime (or worse in case of `sort`) which makes overall `sortEvo` runtime quadratic.

Comment: I left an answer, but reviewing your question well may not be exactly what you want. Can you check this out for me so I can edit?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @Bergi

Comment: why not use two indices form start and end and omit mutating the given data?

Comment: @NinaScholz can you please give me an example?

Comment: In my opinion it would be interesting to use regular expressions to separate words (repeated letters) / letters, for example: 'aaabbbcde' => '[' aaa ',' bbb ',' c ',' d ',' and ']' then order this array in order of text size, then the 'new string' would be the result of iterating from those with more text to those with less text

Comment: For example, we have:

'aaabbbcdddde'

array: ['dddd', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'c', 'and']

the rule to add would be to take the first character of the first key and remove the first character from the array, leaving 'ddd', then go to the next one, in this case 'aaa' and do the same, the next character should be 'd' again, because it still has many characters

Comment: And so it repeats the process to eliminate one by one

Comment: @AksJacoves it sounds like you're talking about using an object to count it. That is the first solution I have written. However, I can't get O(n) with it, just O(n^2). It works beautifully, but I'm looking to achieve this in O(n)

Comment: Understand. I'll try to think of an alternative, I found the question interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a linear time complexity, you could take an object for keeping `indices` for an array of arrays.

In the loop check if a character exists in `indices`, if not create one or incremeent the index for the target array. Then add this character to the target array.

Finally return the flatted and joined array.

```js
function maxDistance(string) {
    var indices = {},
        parts = [];
    
    for (const c of string) {
        if (c in indices) indices[c]++;
        else indices[c] = 0;
        
        let i = indices[c];
        if (!parts[i]) parts[i] = [];
        parts[i].push(c);
    }
    return parts.flat().join('');
}

console.log(maxDistance('aaabbcc'));
```

Comment: Awesome idea, but it doesn't cover much edge cases, still, color me impressed!